# How to fetch the innerText based of a tag if the value has 'translate'

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, angular7, translate

I have the tag in my DOM as follows, how to get the innerText?

```
<p id="on-board" class="on-board-text" *ngIf="(user$|async) as user">
{{
  'OVERVIEW.WELCOME_SCREEN_ON_BOARD'
    | translate
      : {
          USER_NAME:
            user.usrFullNm
        }
}}</p>
```

I am trying to fetch the innerText of it as follows,

```
 find('.on-board-text').nativeElement.innerText;    // -->  ' '
```

The above step coming as empty,where as if I remove 'translate' I am able to get the value.

Comment: Have you tried adding a #onBoard to the <p> element then adding a @ViewChild('onBoard') onBoard to your component and accessing it that way. Idk if that would help but that is the more "Angular" way of doing that so maybe.

Answer (score 0):

try:
`find('.on-board-text').text()`;
then parse for the content you need